# Logstash smaller footprint download

Tags: unix, bigdata, logstash, elastic-stack

I see that the `Logstash 1.4.2 tar` install via the below curl command is around 140 MB & am wondering if there is a way to get smaller footprint download without the extra baggage of `Kibana`, `ElasticSearch`, some `filters`, `inputs`,`outputs`. Is it safe to purge the `vendor` directory.
The latest version of `Logstash 1.5.0` appears to have grown bigger in size & is about 160MB.
Would appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendation and /or inputs around the same.

```
curl -s https://download.elasticsearch.org/logstash/logstash/logstash-1.4.2.tar.gz | tar xz
```

Comment: 4 GB? That tarball is 62 MB. (Logstash 1.4.1 is pretty old, by the way.)

Comment: @Magnus: Updated the size to be 140MB & Logstash version to be 1.4.2

Comment: What parts of Logstash do you need, i.e. what inputs, what filters, and what outputs?

Comment: @Magnus: At this time I only need Input (File), Filter(Grok, Ruby), Output(http).

Comment: What did you end up doing here. I know it’s a super old question by I was looking at a similar deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually deleting stuff from the Logstash distribution that you don't think you need in order to save a few tens of megabytes, just use a more light-weight shipper and do all processing on machine that isn't so low on disk space. Some of your choices are [logstash-forwarder](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash-forwarder), [Log Courier](https://github.com/driskell/log-courier), and [NXLog](http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/). These are just a handful of megabytes each (and use far less RAM since they don't run through the JVM).

Alternatively, NXLog's configuration language is quite rich and you can probably use that for doing the processing you need on your leaf nodes without the need for a separate machine for the processing of logs. NXLog's overhead is quite small.

Comment: Aren't these just the shippers which will ship the logs to logstash server. I would still need the logstash server.

Comment: So, In that case my question still stays intact.

Comment: @JohnC: Yes, but I think you're asking the wrong question. Anyway, I've added a paragraph to suggest use of NXLog.

Comment: @John C: NXLog is not only a client side shipper but can also act as a server.